# Deploy third party library to artifactory using pom.xml

Tags: java, maven-3, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy several 3rd party jars using pom.xml to Artifactory. I have access to Artifactory from a Bamboo build server but not from a developer's computer. This is what I got so far.

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Our Artifactory</name>
            <url>http://company.com:8080/artifactory/our-projects</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Snapshot Our Artifactory</name>
            <url>http://company.com:8080/artifactory/our-projects</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>     
            <configuration>
              <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

So far I've mostly found recommendations to use commercial Nexus plugin. How to deploy dependent third party jars to Artifactory using maven plugins?

---

(Update) Using this code I can install jars to LOCAL repository

```
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>install</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar</file>
                <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                <package>jar</package>               
              </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

However, these jars didn't go to the Artifactory. So when i run the next project that relies on ojdbc it fails with JAR not found.

Comment: have you tried "mvn deploy" command?

Comment: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (install) on project dependency-installer: The artifact information is incomplete or
not valid:
  [0]  'packaging' is missing.

Comment: ok, now please try "mvn clean package deploy"